# Schrödinger Semigroup is compact if potential goes to infinity

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, quantum-mechanics, compact-operators, semigroup-of-operators

Several papers (e.g. this one: arXiv:0810.3275v1 [math.SP] 17 Oct 2008 ) claim that if $H=-\Delta+V$ and $V(x)\to\infty$ if $|x|\to\infty$, then the semigroup $e^{-tH}$ is eventually compact.

Does anyone know any references for that? I looked in Reed Simon but couldn't find anything.

Regards, and thanks in advance,

Frank

Comment: Since Theorem XIII.16 in Reed Simon vol 4 states that $H=-\Delta+V$ has compact resolvent, I guess you want to have a reference pointing that $(H+1)^{-1}$ is compact if and only if $e^{-sH}$ is compact (for some, and thus any $s>0$)?

Comment: @mickep A direct proof of the compactness of $e^{-tH}$ would be more satisfactory, but I'd settle for a proof of
$$(H+1)^{-1} \text{ compact }\Leftrightarrow e^{-tH}\text{ compact},$$
too.